# Python Print Order

Tags: python

This is probably a dumb question, but I'm new to programming and I have a recursive function set up that I'm trying to figure out. For any print function in Python, is it necessarily true that lines are printed in the order that they are written in the script OR for larger outputs, is it possible that smaller length outputs can get printed first in the console even though the print statement is later in the code (maybe due to some memory lag)?

Example:

```
 def test_print():
      #don't run this, but was meant for scale. Is there any chance the 1 would print before the list of lists?
      print([[i for i in range(10000)] for j in range(10000)])
      print(1)
```

Comment: If you print content *to different file descriptors*, output can end up out-of-order (in any language, not just Python) if their routes to the TTY are different. Here, you're printing both to stdout, so ordering is guaranteed.

Comment: lines in Python are executed in the same order they are written. You may redefine/change `print` function to change its behaviour. It would be complicated

Answer (score 1):

Print statements pile output into stdout in the order the code was written. Top to bottom. It isn't possible any other way because that's the way the code is interpreted. Memory lag doesn't play any role here because the output to your console is a line for line rendition of the data that was piled into stdout. And the order the data was written to it can't change, so you'll maintain chronology. Of course, you can always play around with the how the print function itself works. But I wouldn't recommend tampering with standard library functions.

Answer (score 1):

As said above, `print()` function is executed in the order which they are in your code. But you yourself can change the order in which you want it executed, after all you have every right to instruct the code to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You'll always get the same order in the output as the order you execute `print()` functions in Python.

Comment: That's not *quite* true in 100% of cases. Consider `python foo.py | tee out` -- content printed to stderr (with `print >>stderr, "hello"` in Python 2, or `print("hello", file=sys.stderr)` in Python 3) can arrive at the TTY before content printed to stdout, because the stdout content goes through the pipe. But without the print being modified with a file to write to, the guarantee holds.

Comment: Does adding the flag `flush=True` change that?

Comment: That's up to the terminal though. Provided you're line buffered and printing out lines, your process will always produce output in the right order.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque, flushing content forces it to go out the pipeline immediately, but doesn't cause the `tee` instance on the other end of the FIFO to flush it to the TTY immediately (that program still gets scheduled whenever the OS schedules it).

Comment: @viraptor, as soon as you put asynchronously-scheduled pipelines into play, that's just not true. `python foo.py > >(tee out) 2> >(tee err)` has ordering of writes between the two files (when interleaved) that's completely nondeterministic, even though `tee` doesn't do any buffering (writes contents as soon as it can).